# Some doubts regarding the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code in JavaScript which will display some items and hide others and by clicking `"Show more"` option it will display more items.
But it can't go back to the initial state.
By clicking the same button I want it to go to the initial state also.

Can anybody help me?

Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li><a href=# class=show>Show More</a></li>
    </ul>
<script>
    $("li:gt(2):not(:last-child)").hide();
    $('.show').click(function() {
        $("li:gt(2)").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No need to write your question with a bold font you know.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$("li:gt(2)").show();
```

try

```
$("li:gt(2)").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "go back to the initial state" you mean hide the elements which were shown on the previous click, you can use [the `.toggle()` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for that:

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $("li:gt(2)").toggle();
});
```

For more complex scenarios you'd likely have to track the "state" in some variables and react to those variables accordingly.